# Por que meu if não retorna true?

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<img src="image/img1.jpg" alt="">  
  
<script>

  var img = window.document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src;

  if (img.src == "image/img1.jpg")
  {
    console.log("É igual");
  }

  else {
    console.log("Não é igual");
  }

    // console.log(img);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

No código acima o `if` compara se `"image/img1.jpg"` é igual a `"image/img1.jpg"` porque ele retorna o `false` que é `Não é igual`, não era para retornar `true` e executar `É igual`?

Comment: `var img = window.document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src;` você já está inicializando `img` com o valor da propriedade `src`. Remova o src aqui, ou remova o src dentro do if.

Comment: Não funcitonou remover o src da variável e nem do if ele executa else do mesmo jeito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na linha:

```
var img = window.document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src;
```

Retorna o caminho absoluto da imagem. E dentro do `if` você está pegando novamente o `.src`:

```
       ↓↓↓↓
if (img.src == "image/img1.jpg"){
   ...
}
```

Ou seja, `img.src` irá retornar *undefined*, e sempre cairá no `else`.

O que você queria fazer na verdade era comparar o valor da variável `img` (sem o `.src`) com o caminho relativo da imagem:

```
if (img == "image/img1.jpg"){
   ...
}
```

Mas irá sempre cair o `else` porque o o valor de `img` será o caminho absoluto, que é diferente do relativo `image/img1.jpg`.

O que você pode fazer é usar o método `.getAttribute()` para pegar o valor exato do atributo `src` da imagem, e não o caminho absoluto, e comparar no `if`:

```
var img = window.document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute("src");

if(img == "image/img1.jpg"){
   console.log("É igual");
}else{
   console.log("Não é igual");
}

console.log(img); // imprime: image/img1.jpg
```

Comment: Boa, funcionou, valeu!

Answer (score 2):

Você já está usando a propriedade src quando pega o elemento, porém a propriedade src pode trazer o caminho absoluto da imagem, então tenta fazer um contido (includes):

```
<script>
  var img = window.document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];

  if (img.src.includes("image/img1.jpg"))
  {
    console.log("É igual");
  }
  else {
    console.log("Não é igual");
  }
</script>
```

Ou:

```
<script>
  var img = window.document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src;

  if (img.includes("image/img1.jpg"))
  {
    console.log("É igual");
  }
  else {
    console.log("Não é igual");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Valeu, funcionou aqui obrigado, mas só uma dúvida como você disse que  "a propriedade src pode trazer o caminho absoluto da imagem", eu joguei no console a variável img para ver o valor de src e ele amostrou o url absoluto, então eu comparei o src com o url absoluto e rotornou false, porque?

Comment: Não simulei essa situação, faz um console.log(img.src) pra ver se os valores realmente são iguais, usa o próprio console do navegador pra fazer a comparação, pode te ajudar.

Comment: Testei mais ele sempre cai no false e executa o else.